# Parsing a C string and storing parts of the string in variables

Tags: c, string

This post might be marked as a duplicate, but I did search online for this specific case and I couldn't find any examples similar to this. The following is a simplified version of my code.

I have the following lines of data stored with a text file named `test.txt`:

```
12345|This is a sentence|More words here
24792|This is another sentence|More words here again
```

The text in the `test.txt` file will always follow the format of `<int>|<string>|<string>`

I now want to store each of the sections separated by the delimiter `|` in a variable.

The following is my attempt:

```
uint32_t num;
char* str1, str2;

// the data variable is a char pointer to a single line retrieved from test.txt
sscanf(data, "%d|%s|%s", &num, str1, str2);
```

This code above would retrieve the correct value for `num` but would insert the first word from section two into `str1`, leaving the variable `str2` as null. To my understanding, this was the case because the `sscanf()` function stops when it hits a space.

Is there an efficient way of storing each section into a variable?

Comment: Use `strtok` to split the line at the `'|'` characters, and `strdup` to make copies of the two strings.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, `%s` uses whitespace as the delimiter. To use `|` as the delimiter, use `%[^|]`. This matches any sequence of characters not including `|`.

And since `num` is unsigned, you should use `%u`, not `%d`.

```
sscanf(data, "%u|%[^|]|%[^|]", &num, str1, str2);
```

Don't forget to allocate memory for `str1` and `str2` to point to; `scanf()` won't do that automatically.

Your variable declarations are also wrong. It needs to be:

```
char *str1, *str2;
```

Your declaration is equivalent to:

```
char *str1;
char str2;
```

Comment: Hi, I malloc'd both strings with `char* str1 = malloc(25*sizeof(char));` and used the syntax you've provided me above, but the program keeps on telling me that the memory could not be written.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that would happen. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Unless you have a sentence longer than 24 characters.

Comment: I'm running it in VSCode and the error message says something like "The instruction at <address> referenced memory at <address>. The memory could not be written." And yes, I tried shortening to the string in section two and three to 3 chars and it still wouldn't run.

Comment: If you initialized both variables with `malloc()` then that shouldn't happen. Try using ordinary arrays: `char str1[25], str2[25];`

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening during the `sscanf()`?

Comment: Yup. I opened another file and directly tried it in the main method without anything else. Let me try answering my own question so that I could post the entire block of code for my main method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231435/discussion-between-echidna-and-barmar).